# Select input from multiple sources

Tags: anylogic

How can I choose from one of multiple sources? Something like 
`source = one-of [sources] with available?` but my current logic results in feeding all 3 parts. I tried using the hold but it still feeds from all 3 sources.

[image]

A pallet enters from `orders` and when it reaches `assembler`, `holdForPallet` is `unblocked()`. My intention is to use a single component from one of the suSources. A suSource may not have a part available and therefore we have more than one suSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many different ways are possible. One would be to set the 3 sources to "Arrivals defined by" = "calls of inject() function".

Then, your orders source can call `sourceNeeded.inject()` to create one.

Another option: keep the 3 sources as is but add "Wait" objects after each. Now, your orders source can pull in from a specific "Wait" object using `myWaitObject.free(x)`